# reversed() vs. xrange()

Tags: python, list, traversal, xrange

I need to traverse a list backwards. I read about xrange() and reversed(). Which one is more expensive?

Comment: `xrange` and `reversed` do completely different things?

Comment: Are you asking whether you should use off-by-one-error prone `xrange(n, -1, -1)` or whether is just as fast `reversed(xrange(n+1))`? According to `%timeit`, both are about equally fast.

Comment: I point you at the documentation for [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) "If the `__reversed__()` method is not provided, the `reversed()` built-in will fall back to using the sequence protocol (`__len__()` and `__getitem__()`). Objects that support the sequence protocol should only provide `__reversed__()` if they can provide an implementation that is more efficient than the one provided by `reversed()`."

Comment: and `xrange` provides the `__reversed__` method, that's why they score equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#module-timeit) library to time things like this. You don't say what kind of list you have, so I am assuming a simple list of strings. First I create a list 100 items long and then time both:

```
my_list = ["hello"] * 100

def v1():
    for x in my_list[::-1]:
        pass

def v2():
    for x in reversed(my_list):
        pass

print timeit.timeit(v1)
print timeit.timeit(v2)
```

This gives the following result:

```
2.78170533583
2.13084949985
```

As you can see, in this example `reversed()` is a bit faster.

Comment: No use if the list creation is inside the measurement. (Otherwise +1)

Comment: Indeed, well spotted.

Comment: New into this, pretty clear, and geez, learned about timeit. Thanks! 
I'm working with simple lists indeed. And as a backend implementation, I needed  to know which costs less time. So, pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

[`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=xrange#xrange) produces a sequence of numbers.  You can then use those numbers as list indices if you want, or you can use them for anything where you want those numbers.

```
for i in xrange( len(l)-1, -1, -1):
    item = l[i]
    print item
```

[`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) produces the items from something that has a length and can be indexed.

```
for item in reversed(l):
    print item
```

I would use `reversed()` because it makes you code shorter, simpler, clearer, and easier to write correctly.

Comment: You can also use a generator `for item in (l[i] for i in xrange(len(l)-1, -1, -1)): ...`. (Caution: can cause other people to hate you when they have to read the code.)

Comment: Indeed ... you could then put your generator in a function and call it reversed().  : )